# Is it possible to narrow union type with NonNullable outside of function call?

Tags: typescript, composition, union-types

I have this useCase class where I fetch Invoice object from repository. Its type is the union of `Invoice|null` Then I pass this object to validation function which does not return anything - it just throws if something is not right. How can I describe function's type so that after calling `await verifyEntityVisibilityInCurrentContext(...)` the `invoice` variable is narrowed only to type Invoice? I tried the NonNullable approach mentioned in this article, but it is hard for me to implement it. https://blog.logrocket.com/when-to-use-never-and-unknown-in-typescript-5e4d6c5799ad/

#### The code:

```
export class GetRelatedDocumentsUseCase {

  private async getInvoiceRelatedDocuments(invoiceId: string, ctx: Context) {
    const invoice: Invoice|null = await this.invoicesRepository.findOneInvoiceById(invoiceId);

    await verifyEntityVisibilityInCurrentContext(invoice, ctx, permissionDeniedMessage, this.companiesRepository);

    //I want here invoice variable to be only of type Invoice
    await doSomethingWithInvoiceObject(invoice)
  }

}


// Helper function - I tried to describe its return type with `never` or apply some code from the article

export async function verifyEntityVisibilityInCurrentContext(
 entity, ctx: Context, permissionDeniedMessage, companiesRepository) :Promise<never | void> {
  if (isNil(entity)) {
    throw new PermissionDenied(permissionDeniedMessage);
  }
  if (!isObjectVisibleInContext(entity, ctx)) {
    const company = await companiesRepository.findCompanyById(entity.companyId);
    const companyUser = company.users.find(companyUser => companyUser.userId === ctx.userId);

    if (isNil(companyUser)) {
      throw new PermissionDenied(permissionDeniedMessage);
    }

    throw new NotFoundInCurrentCompany({
      desiredCompanyId: entity.companyId,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `await doSomethingWithInvoiceObject(invoice!);` ?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this feature. But it seems hacky, for me, isn't it?

Comment: Please consider editing this code into a [mcve] in which the only problem is the one you're having; as it stands there are quite a number of undefined types and values, which prevents someone from dropping this into an IDE and answering your question.  I'd suggest making your `verifyEntityVisibility...()` function return the non-null invoice object and have the calling function use that.  You might need to make that function generic so the returned object is type `Invoice` instead of `any` or whatever it is now.  I'll elaborate if you make this into a [mcve].  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type verification function

```
isInvoice = (arg: Invoice|null): arg is Invoice => {
        return arg !== null ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: I know this approach, but I don't want to use any `if` flow commands

Answer (score 0):

You're already throwing errors in your helper.  What you want to do is throw an additional error when `invoice` is `null`.  Typescript will automatically refine the type from `Invoice | null` to just `Invoice` below the `if ( ! invoice )` branch.

```
private async getInvoiceRelatedDocuments(invoiceId: string, ctx: Context): Promise<Invoice> {
    const invoice: Invoice|null = await this.invoicesRepository.findOneInvoiceById(invoiceId);

    await verifyEntityVisibilityInCurrentContext(invoice, ctx, permissionDeniedMessage, this.companiesRepository);

    if ( ! invoice ) {
        throw new Error("null invoice");
    }
    // now variable is only type Invoice
    await doSomethingWithInvoiceObject(invoice);
    return invoice;
}
```